# Finding source jar for binary jat

Tags: java, jar

Example of situation. I use xercesimpl-2.8.1.jar in java project(Eclipse).
It's linked as a library. For debugging I downloaded xercesImpl-2.8.1-sources.jar.
I paired two these by:

- Eclipse Project: Properties\Java Build Path\Libraries\Source Attachment
- Browsing in source code for some type, them "Change Attached Source".

Both had no effect implying that 2 jar are strangers. However, reviewing of archive contents predicts they are similar.

Questions:

1. How (best practice) to find source for binary jar?
2. How to pair it in project?
3. What's in structure makes them able to pair?
4. Is it Eclipse or jre component that links them together?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your project a Maven or a Gradle project and define the Xerces library as a dependency. Then Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA could get the source code of the dependency automatically, in case there is the source code in the repository. In most cases there is a source code in the repository.

For example Xerces:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.1 (definition of dependency)

http://central.maven.org/maven2/xerces/xercesImpl/2.8.1/ (files in the repository)

Comment: It depends on external repositories. Sometimes you need it purely local.

Comment: @user1439579 this is exactly what I wrote in my answer. In your case the central repository contains the source code of the Xerces library.